# Why do I have to press enter Twice?

Tags: c++, iostream

For some reason in my program when I reach a certain spot, I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice in order to get it to submit. I added the clear to keep it from skipping input and the ignore() to keep it from keeping any extra characters in the buffer. I enter my input and then it drops down to a new line, I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again and it enter the input and continues the program no problem but I'm wondering why. Here's a code snippet:

```
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter Student Major (ex. COSC): ";
    cin.getline(student.major, 6);

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(student.major); i++)
        student.major[i] = toupper(student.major[i]);

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of ``cin.clear()`` and ``cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')`` ?

Comment: If I get rid of both and the user goes over the character limit then my program crashes.

Comment: Ya either a carriage return is entered automatically, or you have to enter carriage return twice, absolutely maddening!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that you are tossing too many [`cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) around, not knowing exactly why they are needed and when to put them there.

There are two common circumstances where `cin.ignore()` is needed to "make input work right":

1. when mixing formatted and unformatted input;
2. to recover from a formatted input error.

In both cases, you want to get rid of spurious characters from the input buffer; if there isn't any such character (which is probably what happens in your program), `cin.ignore()` will pause the execution and wait for user input - after all, you asked it to ignore some characters, and dammit, it will obey to its orders.

(although `ignore()` by default would "eat" just one character, whatever it may be, the execution is paused until a newline is found because by default `cin` is line buffered - new input is not examined until a newline is recieved)

#### Case 1:

`cin.ignore()` calls are often needed if you are performing an *unformatted input* operation (like `getline`) after performing a *formatted input* operation (i.e. using the `>>` operator).

This happens because the `>>` operator leaves the newline in the input buffer; that's not a problem if you are performing only formatted input operations (by default they skip all the whitespace before trying to interpret the input), but it's a problem if afterwards you do unformatted input: `getline` by default reads until it finds a newline, so the "spurious newline" left will make it stop reading immediately.

So, here you will usually call `cin.ignore(...)` call to get rid of the newline just after the last formatted input operation you do in a row, guaranteeing that the input buffer is empty. Afterwards, you can call `getline` directly without fear, knowing that you left the buffer empty.

It's a bad idea, instead, to put it *before* any `getline`, as you seem to do in your code, since there may be code paths that lead to that `getline` that have the input buffer clean, so the `ignore` call will block.

#### Case 2:

when `istream` encounters an error in a formatted input operations, it leaves the "bad" characters in the buffer, so if you retry the operation you get stuck endlessly, since the offenders are still there. The usual `clear()/ignore()` idiom comes to the rescue, removing the whole offending line from the input buffer.

Again, you don't put the `clear()/ignore()` sequence at random, but only after you get an input error from a formatted input operation (which sets the failbit of the stream).

---

Now, aside from these cases, it's uncommon to use `cin.ignore()` (unless you actually want to skip characters); don't spread it around randomly "just to be safe", because otherwise you will encounter the problem you described.

Comment: Another case for `cin.ignore` is to *pause* the console until the User presses Enter.

Comment: Right, the main reason I've been using `ignore()` is to ignore any unneeded characters at the end of the input. If I'm asking for 1 Character and the user types in garble I just want to pull that one character.

Answer (score 0):

I think `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` is expecting a `\n` in the input and it doesn't find it, so you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again for it to find it.

Comment: if I get rid of the '\n' in my ignore, it never goes to the next input and I just keep pressing enter.

Comment: just comment the line and see if it works: ``//cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');``

Comment: if I comment out the whole line, then it fubbles up my next line of input.

Comment: What if you put ``cin.get();`` instead of ``cin.clear();`` and ``cin.ignore(numeric...`` ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).

> The extraction ends when n characters have been extracted and discarded or when the character delim is found, whichever comes first. In the latter case, the delim character itself is also extracted.

So in your case, the program will not continue until a `'\n'` character is received.

Comment: See my comment on the post answer below.