# Why do I have to press enter twice in C++ for get line?

Tags: c++, cin

Why is it that when I run this code, the `cout` statement is only executed after I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key twice?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char buf[128];
    cin.getline(buf, 128, '\n');
    cout << buf;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix it?

I'm using Xcode Version 4.5.2 on OS X Lion. I tried running the program in Terminal and it requires two <kbd>return</kbd> presses too.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556890/why-do-i-have-to-press-enter-twice), but with less code so the solution should be clearer. I.e. in the other question, people were saying that the problem is the `cin.ignore()`, however, my code doesn't have that.

---

**Other code I tried which failed:**

This produces the same exact behavior:

```
    cin.getline(buf, 128);
```

This never moves on to the next line (no matter how many times the <kbd>return</kbd> key is pressed):

```
    cin.getline(buf, 128, '\r');
```

Comment: Is that everything in `main`?

Comment: Not sure, but I think since you've specified the delimiter as \n, \n must be typed twice. First to add a line, second to give the line to cin.getline. Try removing the specification, i.e. `cin.getline(buf, 128);`

Comment: For me it gets executed for enter key pressed just once.

Comment: Its been a while since I've been on OSX, but aren't their carriage returns \r instead of \n ?

Comment: @txtechhelp: replacing with \r causes the input to never stop. I can press enter 100 times and it won't move to the next line.

Comment: @AStupidNoob: Running it without \n has the same exact behavior.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish specifically? Are you trying to read data into buf from the standard input or just trying to get what someone enters?

Comment: Does `fgets` have the same problem?

Comment: @DhruvPathak: That got me thinking that it might be a problem with my compiler, so I switched it and indeed it started working properly again, so thanks!

Comment: @Senseful Nevermind then, Just a wild guess. Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It appears to be a problem with the compiler.

When I go to my project in Xcode and switch the compiler from **Default compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 4.1)** to **LLVM GCC 4.2** everything works properly.

Comment: Probably the first compiler's getline function returns the `\n` char to the stdin after reading.